# What is that thing called that Ed Sheeran is doing with his voice on the word "no"?

Tags: voice, vocal-cords

[What is that thing called that Ed Sheeran is doing with his voice on the word "no". It sounds like shouting but how does he do that?](https://youtu.be/K0ibBPhiaG0?t=237)

Comment: Surely '*know*'/

Comment: @Tim Sorry, I didn't paid attention to the lyrics. Yes it's definitely  "know".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's one of the many forms of vocal "distortion".

You'll hear it far more often in rock and metal singing styles.

You might want to check out youtube videos on singing with rasp and distortion by the likes of Ken Tamplin (other vocal coaches are of course available!).

If you are wanting to do it and starting out as a singer that has never done it, go easy on your voice.

Comment: When I was a boy I tried to sing like Louis Armstrong and I think I disturbed my voice by distortion in the age  of 14.

Comment: Yes, but why of all things Ken Tamplin? He's spreading so much misconception/bad technique and we know how dangerous this can be with harsh vocals.